# ORA-01008: not all variables bound after database upgrade

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've got an Oracle Error (**ORA-01008**): the thing is that this error appears for the first time, with no modification of table/Schema (but there was a database upgrade).
I tried execute immediate, but I still get the same error.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
set define off;
--alter session set "_subquery_pruning_enabled"=false; 
DECLARE
  z_value NUMBER      := -1;
  CURSOR listedocument
  IS
  select to_number(2310458) as coco from dual;
BEGIN
  FOR l IN listedocument
  LOOP
    BEGIN
          dbms_output.put_line (' l.coco= ' ||  l.coco );
         SELECT oa.myvalue
           INTO z_value
           FROM    schema2.table2 oa
                INNER JOIN
                   schema1.table1 ed
                ON ed.coco = oa.coco
          WHERE ed.coco =  l.coco
         ;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('NO_DATA_FOUND');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('Exception de traitement ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The problem seems to be here `WHERE ed.coco =  l.coco`
<s>I get the error : **Exception de traitement ORA-01008: not all variables bound**</s> [*==>modification post message*]

I get the error : **ORA-01008: not all variables bound**

When I use `alter session set "_subquery_pruning_enabled"=false;` everything works, but performance is bad.

I'm using Oracle database 11g (11.2.0.4.0).

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about "ORA-01008: not all variables bound".  please don't invent new error messages by translating French to English - putting ORA-01008 into your favourite search engine will return the correct English term. Also, I'd be interested where you got the idea to use the non-documented '_subquery_pruning_enabled' parameter - is this taken from Metalink?

Comment: I cant see any bind variables are used in this case.!!!

Comment: Could you try to disable to Dynamic sampling and try. I think it might help.  alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling = 0

Comment: Looks like you might need to raise a service request with Oracle.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : you're right, I correct my original message.

Comment: @AvrajitRoy : I tried to disable Dynamic sampling, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have hit a bug.
Take a look:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3894065?start=30&tstart=0

> There are cases where the optimizer calls kkpap to do partition
>   pruning at compile-time. Sometimes partition pruning is done by
>   running subqueries against the table. If bind variable values are
>   required to run these subqueries then we cannot do the pruning at
>   compile-time.
>       The fix for  bug 14458214  fixed this issue for the case where the   subquery was used to prune at the partition-level. However, it is
>   possible that we use some other method at the partition level then use
>   subquery pruning at the subpartition level; this case was not
>   addressed by the fix for 14458214.

Comment: Exactly, that's where I found the solution of `_subquery_pruning_enabled`. But it seems to decrease performance. Another solution was to applied a `to_number` to **ed.coco** like `to_number(ed.coco) =  l.coco`, but performance is bad and I can't explain the original problem.

Comment: If you have access to oracle support you should install the patch (if available) or contact them IMHO

Comment: No I don't, and I'm not the DBA. But I did some tests: first, my request work on other environnement. Then `schema2.table2` is a view materialized, based on a DBLINK, I used another view materialized (based on same DBLINK) and it worked with the same contraint (oa.coco). After I change `schema2.table2` with the `table2@DBLINK` and it work. So I think there is a problem with that specific view materialized, but i'm not expert to determine what is it (partition, etc.)...

Comment: @FTK I've read that it might have something to do with unusable indexes. have you tried `alter session set skip_unusable_indexes=false;`?

Comment: I've just tried it, but I have another exception `ORA-01502: index "string.string" or partition of such index is in unusable state`

Comment: Ok, so it looks you have an unusable index and the query is trying to use it. Maybe you should see whose is the unusable index and try to avoid it using an index hint on another index (if possible)

Comment: Exactly, I did like he said (https://community.oracle.com/message/13667985#13667985) index were unusables...so i rebuild them (`alter index cds.snapshot_pk rebuild partition p_13118;`) and it work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114202/discussion-between-ftk-and-vercelli).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE

  z_value NUMBER      := -1;


coco number;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
coco:=2310458;
          dbms_output.put_line (' coco= ' ||  coco );
         SELECT oa.myvalue
           INTO z_value
           FROM    schema2.table2 oa
                INNER JOIN
                   schema1.table1 ed
                ON ed.coco = oa.coco
          WHERE ed.coco =  coco
         ;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('NO_DATA_FOUND');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('Exception de traitement ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
```

Using LOOP when You have 1 variable in cursor... not a good idea.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Also, using a loop to iterate over 1 (or 0 ) rows is perfectly fine (although seldom necessary).

Comment: I selected one variable, to simplify my cursor. But in real, the cursor get more than one value.